# I have a txt file from where I need to read it into memory - It has the details of childname, age, height

Tags: java, sorting, file-io, average, comparator

I have a txt file from where I need to read it into memory - It has the details of childname, age, height in the comma separated format in each line as below -

Alex,27,172
George, 45,180

...

..

The requirement is to read the details and provide-

 1. the details of the child who is tallest
 2. the details of the child who is shortest
 3. the details of the child who is eldest
 4. the details of the child who is youngest
 5. the average height of the children of each age
 6. the average age of the children of each height

How can I provide an efficient solution in java?

I've tried with a List of Pojos(with details - name, age, height), and 2 comparators for age and height - where after i sort it, I get the child objects with eldest/youngest age and tallest/shortest height. Is there any more efficient way to do it? 
Also, how do I find the average height/age corresponding to the age/height respectively? Which collection would be a good fit here?

Comment: What makes you think you need to "read it into memory"?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide details of how the file is formatted, the answer to this cannot be specific.

In general, I would create a child class with the various details.  Read each child from your file and create an instance of the child class.  Then I would do something like the following-

```
class Children {

    private ArrayList<Child> children;

    public Children(ArrayList<Child> input){
        children = input;
        }

    public Child tallest(){
        Child tallest;
        for (Child child : children){
            if (tallest != null){
                if (child.getHeight() > tallest.getHeight()){
                    tallest = child;
                    }
                }
            else {
                tallest = child;
                }
            }
        return tallest;
        }

        etc...
```

There are a variety of ways to read in the input file ... if it is saved in xml format, or csv format, or text with a newline in between- each is slightly different.